# Arctext.js Responsive Text

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, arctext.js

I'm using arctext.js to make a curved styled look. However, when using media screen, it doesn't help to downscale the font site when in responsive mode. 
I do have viewpoint and using bootstrap 4. 
Are there other options to downscale the font to fit mobile devices?

[Arctext.js](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/24/arctext-js-curving-text-with-css3-and-jquery/)

HTML

```
<div class="mainimg">
    <div class="container-fluid maintxt">
    <h1 id="curve" class="mainh1 mb-4">Krista Andrews</h1>
        <p>Front-End Web Developer &amp; Digital Designer</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
        $().ready(function() {
            $('#curve').arctext({radius: 400});
        });
    </script>
<script src="jquery.arctext.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
.mainimg{
    background-image: url("images/one.jpg");
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px), (min-width: 300px) {
  div.mainimg {
    background-image: url("images/one.jpg");
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
    width:100%;
  }
}
.maintxt{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
}
.mainh1{
    font-family: 'Chonburi', cursive;
    font-size:2.5em;
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Add some Code snippet to support your question